# MySQL - bulk inserting data with datetime and timestamp fields

Tags: mysql

So, I'm playing around with a database trying to learn MySQL. I've got a script together that creates a database and am not trying to bulk populate the data. Everything seems fine except for my fields that are datetime and timestamp.

Here's the table I'm having the issue with:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestMsgs;
CREATE TABLE TestMsgs (
    msg_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    user_id int,
    content varchar(200), 
    time_submitted datetime,
    last_update timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (msg_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

So, I want to manually set the datetime when a record is added, and then auto update the timestamp every time a record is updated.

When I try to batch populate the following data:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "testmsgs.txt" REPLACE INTO TABLE TestMsgs
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' (user_id, content, time_submitted);

content of testmsgs.txt:
    1|test1|10/22/2013 10:30
    1|test2|10/22/2013 10:31
    1|test3|10/22/2013 10:32
```

I get the following results:

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------+
|  msg_id  | user_id | content | time_submitted      | last_update |
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------+
|        1 |       1 | test1   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL        |
|        2 |       1 | test2   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL        |
|        3 |       1 | test3   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL        |
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------+
```

What gives? What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's TIMESTAMP/DATETIME format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. You're doing `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM`, so MySQL hasn't the first clue what to do with it. You'll need to convert with MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE` function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Your comment about date formatting is correct. However in this case, since the import is using `LOAD DATA ... INFILE` syntax, there is no way to make `STR_TO_DATE()` conversion on import, so the underlying data in the file would need to be modified.

Comment: @MikeBrant One possible solution there is making that column a `VARCHAR`, then doing the conversion after import into a new column.

Answer (score 0):

Please note what @ceejayoz has said about proper format for datetime and timestamp fields.

To make your timestamp field work the way you want, you need to change your `last_update` field definition to be as follows:

```
last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` definition provide current timestamp on record creation.
The `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` definition provides the functionality to update the timestamp on record changes.